# Running .NUnit files programmatically

Tags: c#, nunit

.nunit files are not running when using NUNIT in C#

I have tried running below code, but the error returned is that the file is not supported. All the examples on the internet use .dll as the path for a testpackage, not .unit.

According to below sites, it is possible to run .unit files:
https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Writing-Engine-Extensions and
https://github.com/nunit/nunit-project-loader/tree/master/src/extension

```
 var path = @"path to nunit file";      
        var package = new TestPackage(path);
        var engine = TestEngineActivator.CreateInstance();


        using (var runner = engine.GetRunner(package))
        {      
            var result = runner.Run(this, TestFilter.Empty);
        }  
    }
```

I have tried the following by referencing nunitprojectloader dll:

```
        var path = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\nunit-project-loader-master\nunit-project-loader-master\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\DEV.nunit";
        NUnitProjectLoader pl = new NUnitProjectLoader();
        pl.LoadFrom(path); 
        var package = pl.GetTestPackage(path);         
        var engine = TestEngineActivator.CreateInstance();


        using (var runner = engine.GetRunner(package))
        {
            // execute the tests            
            var result = runner.Run(this, TestFilter.Empty);
        }
```

There is a new error by doing this: 
It tries running NBi.NUnit.Runtime.dll which is referenced in the nunit file. 
Everythings works fine using the console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Run NUnit Tests from C# Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825918/how-to-run-nunit-tests-from-c-sharp-code)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski that examples shows it running tests with .dll extension. I need help with .nunit extensions.

Comment: Have you installed the NUnit project loader extension?

Comment: @Charlie yes. I have a reference to nunitprojectloader dll in my C sharp project. I can load the .nunit file but my test cases are in a separate nbits file. It does not seem to load the tests.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a problem with NUnit at all, but an NBi problem. NBi uses `.nbits` files, which have nothing to do with `.nunit` files.

Comment: A cursory examination of the NBi documentation seems to indicate that they work with NUnit framework V2, not NUnit 3. I can't verify this, however.